Are all pass filters stable?
I have the following Z-transform for a filter:
$$ \frac{1-1/2z^{-1}}{1-2z^{-1}}$$
This is an all pass filter. The pole is located at $z=2$ which is outside the unit circle. Does that mean this filter is not stable?
If this filter was implemented in the frequency domain (using FFT and overlap-and-save), there are no issues. So I am confused.


Are all pass filters stable?

No. Allpass filters have the same stability criteria as any other IIR filters: the poles need to be inside the unit circle.

The pole is located at $z=2$ which is outside the unit circle. Does that mean this filter is not stable?

Yes. The filter is unstable.

If this filter was implemented in the frequency domain (using FFT and overlap-and-save), there are no issues. So I am confused.

You can't implement an IIR filter with overlap add. Overlap-add only implements FIR filters, so you would have to truncate the IIR response.

So I am confused.

There is a bit of nuance here. If you invert your filter, you actually get a perfectly causal and stable allpass filter with a pole at $z=0.5$. The inverse of a causal & stable allpass filter is ALSO an allpass filter but it's infinitely non-causal. The impulse response is flipped in time. That's why you can't implement it exactly.
The best you can do is to truncate the response add bulk delay (which makes the overall response stable and causal)
